# WPF Window and ViewBox aspect ratio

Tags: wpf

I have a question about how to achieve a particular layout in WPF.

I have a simple Window containing a ViewBox (set to “Uniform”). Inside the ViewBox is a vertical StackPanel containing two items; a Calendar up top and a grid with some text down below. The ViewBox is set to stretched (vertically and horizontally) so resizing the Window zooms the content in and out (as expected and desired).

[image: Window Layout]

I would like to make it so that when the Window is resized, that the aspect ratio of the ViewBox and Window are synched up i.e. I would basically like to lock the Window and ViewBox together.

Thanks for any thoughts….

Comment: have you tried to set MaxWidth and MaxHeight if windows is resize beyond that limit controls will not resize or grow

Comment: What you're describing should already be happening. The Window only contains a ViewBox, so they should have the same aspect ratio. Can you expand on what you're expecting the behavior to be?